# The flag window disappears and text is deleted when clicking elsewhere

Tags: feature-request

I was writing a text to explain why I'd like to flag an item, but when I accidentally clicked on the SO page itself the flag window disappeared and deleted what I wrote. Is it possible to make text just written available even after some clicking and scrolling on the same page?

It's somewhat annoying to have to write the same thing twice...

Comment: Just curious, what text were you writing?  Most flags don't require text (and mod intervention).

Comment: I wrote one to request moderator intervention because I can't do much more than that with my rep. (The question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923471/good-literature-on-unit-testing and I flagged it because it's just another question asking for literature, but neither spam nor inappropriate.)

Comment: You could flag it as "should be closed". A mod is not needed for that. This is available at [15 imaginary points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: @codeMagic _"Please note that the comment privilege is also linked to the flagging privilege. In the flag-to-close menu, **the options to flag as duplicate or as off-topic will not appear** if you do not have sufficient reputation to post a comment because these flag types automatically generate a comment when you submit the flag."_ [Bottom of the Comment Privilege page, emphasis mine.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) Not a reason to use the wrong flag, but a reason they _couldn't_ use the right one.

Comment: @codeMagic As a user with almost no rep I don't have this option. I can edit (which makes no sense here because there is nothing to edit, so it's unlikely that the edit will pass the review and/or draw higher-rep community users's attention to closing it), answer it (same as in edit) or flag it as spam, inappropriate or...ask a moderator. I cannot even comment on other people's questions right now... If I'm overlooking sth., please give me a hint.

Comment: @Kendra exactly. which option should I have chosen instead, in your opinion?

Comment: @Kendra touche. I missed that. FranzWurst yep sorry, I missed that. But it's still not a reason to use the mod flag. The best option is to walk away or you could ask in an appropriate chat for others to close it. But it is an older question (things were different) and has a lot of upvotes.

Comment: @FranzWurst no option.  There is _currently no correct action_ until you hit the 50 rep

Comment: While it's respectable you're trying to keep the site clean, Franz, you shouldn't flag for mod attention on something the community can handle, even if you don't have the rep to flag it correctly. The mods get a ton of flags every day, and doing this only increases their workload. Doing nothing is the correct action here. If you feel that it won't get enough attention to get closed, you could favorite the question and come back to it when you have the rep to flag appropriately.

Comment: @codeMagic okay, thanks, I'll have a look around for that chat then! (didn't know it existed...)

Comment: @Kendra Alright, lesson learned. I'll see if I can recall my flag

Comment: @FranzWurst I didn't really mean any particular chat (though there is a [close vote review chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) but that is more focused on posts currently in the queue). I mean a chat relevant to the tags of which the post contains. Just make sure to read the room rules of any chat you want to join before posting.

Comment: There is no way to cancel flags, and it will likely be declined with a message about using the normal flag options, but at least now you know what's up. :) The important thing is you learned a little bit more today about how the site works, and are on your way to becoming an even better member of the community. I'm sure you'll have the 50 rep for all flags in no time.

Comment: But does anyone have comments on the request I actually posted? It's a good thing to have learnt a few things about the site here, but what about the actual question? Does nobody ever ask a mod, so it's not an issue? :)

Comment: As for your request, I would not personally get much benefit from it.  I've submitted like 3 custom flags.  And the max length for a custom flag is sufficiently small so retyping isn't too bad.

Comment: @codeMagic Then I'll have a look at how the chats work. I do have the privilege to enter those....

Comment: Concerning the actual request, I would say that having to flag for a mod _should_ be rare (as in, you shouldn't need to in most cases and should be able to use other flags instead) per user, so I don't think it's really super needed. While it would be a neat little improvement, I think there are bigger issues that are more... Pressing? Needed? That the developers should be spending their time on instead.

Comment: @Kendra Oh, that's too bad. In that case I'm definitely looking forward to more rep to avoid annoying people around here...

Comment: Hm, I see. I just thought it would be nice to have, but you're probably right, it's rarely ever needed.